# Let's clarify the tag "escritura"

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

We have a "handwriting" tag.  (Maybe I created it -- I have a notoriously bad memory for this sort of thing.)  We also have an "escritura" tag.  I think [escritura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escritura) overlaps too much with [ortografía] (spelling).  I'd like to bring [escritura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escritura) into clearer focus, to align directly with [handwriting](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/handwriting).

I guess handwriting could be "escritura manuscrita" or "escritura a mano."  I have a slight preference for the latter but I'd be fine with the former.

Here's what we currently have for [escritura](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/escritura):

> Preguntas sobre conceptos específicos de la escritura (nombre de los símbolos usados, etc.).

Comment: Hold on with question in Meta, please. You are bringing so many elements into debate and hardly anybody is participating. Try to close debates before going into others, otherwise we will end up with so many status-* things without a proper follow-up.

Comment: @fedorqui - I have learned to wait several weeks after posting at this Meta.  No hurry in thinking about this.

Comment: It seems that the tag "writing" is a synonym of "escritura", but there's none for "handwriting".  To me they seem both synonyms of "punctuation", given that definition. Handwriting is only used in 4 questions, but I don't know how much value the tag is adding to these questions. Maybe one option could be getting rid of that tag, since it seems its use is unclear and "ortografía" or "puntuación" could cover for it.

Comment: @Diego - The beauty of tags is that they make it easier for people to find things.  That is, the purpose of tagging is not just to be able to put some label that seems to fit correction on each question.  The purpose of tagging, as I see it at least, is to assign labels that are as specific as possible on questions, to make it easier to navigate this enormous database of Q&A pairs that we have here.  Looking at it that way, the logic would be, if a *specific* label fits accurately the questions it is associated with, then it is constructive and useful, and should remain.

Comment: But having too many tags that vary in a nuance defeat the purpose of tagging. Everything gets more confusing and difficult to use. Less intuitive. That is also why we have tag synonyms. I would consider how many questions we have with those tags and how they add value

Comment: @Diego - Can you give a couple of examples where too fine a granularity or too many synonyms would reduce value?  I am having trouble imagining such a situation.  Synonyms, for example, are a necessity of life in a bilingual site.