# We have a "lo" tag but no "le" tag

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, etiquetas, reetiquetado

We get lots of beginner and intermediate questions about *lo* and *le*.  We have a "lo" tag but no "le" tag.  Should we create a "le" tag?  Or modify the existing "lo" tag to something like "lo/le"?  (Note, we have "direct-object," "indirect-object" and "pronoun" tags.)

Motivation for asking: A well-organized tagging system helps with closing duplicates, and guiding question formulation to distinguish from possible duplicates.

Comment: I wonder how you digest our comments here. [I said earlier today](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/lets-clarify-the-tag-escritura#comment5002_2898): _Hold on with question in Meta, please. You are bringing so many elements into debate and hardly anybody is participating. Try to close debates before going into others, otherwise we will end up with so many status-* things without a proper follow-up_.

Comment: @fedorqui - Look, I don't mind waiting for responses.  This can sit here for a while until people get around to looking at it.  Just because there's a post sitting in Meta doesn't mean you have to read it and think about it yet.  Especially if it's about tags. // I'm still working my way through the posts about *agreement*.  There are a lot, and since I don't want to tag very many per day, it's going to take a while.

Comment: It is not you minding about it, it is a moderator telling you three times in a day to hold on. Either create a unique question with all the concerns, like I did in [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674) or ask once every few days. Otherwise, activity in Meta will be just blocked by your overwhelming set of tiny questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in [¿Cómo deberíamos etiquetar las preguntas sobre pronombres 'la', 'le' y 'lo' y en las que se observa laísmo, leísmo o loísmo?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/1674), we now have [clíticos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cl%c3%adticos) with multiple synonyms: [le](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/le), [lo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lo), [pronombre-la](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombre-la), [pronombre-le](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombre-le) and [pronombre-lo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronombre-lo).